# Vowel Count in C via recursion

Tags: c, recursion

My code is not responding when I run it, I can't seem to figure out the problem but my best guess is the recursive call portion in the `else` section of the `strcheck`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int alphcheck(char *ptr)
{
    if(*ptr=='a'||*ptr=='e'||*ptr=='i'||*ptr=='o'||*ptr=='u')
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}//close aplhcheck

int strcheck(char *ptr)
{
    int r;

    if(ptr=='\0')
        return 0;
    else 
    {
        r = alphcheck(ptr)+r;
        strcheck(++ptr);
        return r;
    }
}//close strcheck

int main()
{
    int res;
    char name[] = "sahirnoorali";
    res = strcheck(name);
    printf("%d",res);
    return 0;
}//close main
```

Comment: Well, for one: you're using `r` uninitialized, and two: you're not using the return-value of the recursive call.

Comment: And three : `if(ptr=='\0')` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the base case of the recursive function `strcheck`, in this line:

```
     if(ptr=='\0')
```

it should be:

```
     if(*ptr=='\0')
```

Also, the `r` variable was supposed to be another parameter of the function:

```
 int strcheck(char *ptr, int r)
 {
 if(ptr=='\0')
 return 0;

 else 
 {
 // TODO: fix the two lines below:
 r = alphcheck(ptr)+r;
 strcheck(++ptr);
 return r;
 }
```

It is an accumulator: from `main` you should call the function with second parameter equal to 0:

```
res = strcheck(name, 0);
```

Here is the full working code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 int alphcheck(char *ptr)
 {
  return (*ptr=='a'||*ptr=='e'||*ptr=='i'||*ptr=='o'||*ptr=='u') ? 1 : 0;
 }

 int strcheck(char *ptr, int r)
 {
  if(*ptr=='\0') return r;
  else 
  {
   r += alphcheck(ptr);
   return strcheck(++ptr, r);
  }
 }

 int main()
 {
  int res;
  char name[] = "sahirnoorali";
  res = strcheck(name, 0);
  printf("%d\n",res);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It solved the running problem but the output is coming 16384. Now comes the calling problem.

Comment: Thanks. You inversed the call, I liked the style. :)

Answer (score 3):

`r` is uninitialized. This will invoke **undefined behavior** and you may get garbage value. The another one is

```
if(ptr=='\0')
```

You are assigning null terminator to `ptr` which is wrong. You have to use dereference operator `*` and then assign `\0`.

```
if(*ptr=='\0')
```

Comment: Nope it is initialized

Comment: @Sahir You are using `r` in an expression *before* you assign to it. So you are using it when it's uninitialized.

Comment: Okay you mean I declared it but didn't initialize right? but that and doing *ptr isn't solving the problem, it gives 0 as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working pice... There were bugs in your code

```
int strcheck(char *ptr)
{
    static int r = 0; // Declare r as static and initialize it to 0

    if(*ptr=='\0')   // Comparision problem.
        return 0;

    else 
    {
        r = alphcheck(ptr)+r;
        strcheck(++ptr);
        return r;
    }
}
```